# VBA code to delete sheets with partial name is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create code that will delete all sheets in active workbook if name contains part text from input. So far nothing seems working and I have no clue why.

I am using this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton28_Click()

   Dim shName As String
   Dim xName As String
   Dim xWs As Worksheet
   Dim cnt As Integer
   shName = Application.InputBox("Enter the specific text:", "Delete sheets", _
                                   ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name, , , , , 2)
   If shName = "" Then Exit Sub
   xName = "*" & shName & "*"
'    MsgBox xName
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   cnt = 0
   For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
       If xWs.Name Like xName Then
           xWs.Delete
           cnt = cnt + 1
       End If
   Next xWs
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   MsgBox "Have deleted " & cnt & " worksheets", vbInformation, "Sheets removed"


End Sub
```

But when I enter specific text (no spaces before or after) it doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it?
Here is data from sheet where I tested it: [Sheets names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdMXt.png)

And here is the result of macro: [Result of macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBsR4.png)

Comment: As the code should work: Are you really want to delete from `ThisWorkbook`? `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where the code is stored, while `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that currently has the focus.

Comment: As @FunThomas said your code works with spaces or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Like` is case sensitive. Try making the following changes to your code (please see comments starting with `'****`)

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton28_Click()

   Dim shName As String
   Dim xName As String
   Dim xWs As Worksheet
   Dim cnt As Integer
   shName = Application.InputBox("Enter the specific text:", "Delete sheets", _
                                   ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name, , , , , 2)
   If shName = "" Then Exit Sub
   '**** use LCase() here
   xName = "*" & LCase(shName) & "*"
'    MsgBox xName
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   cnt = 0
   For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
       '**** Use LCase() here
       If LCase(xWs.Name) Like xName Then
           xWs.Delete
           'MsgBox xName
           cnt = cnt + 1
       End If
   Next xWs
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   MsgBox "Have deleted " & cnt & " worksheets", vbInformation, "Sheets removed"


End Sub
```

Please also note that your code doesn't check if the sheet to be deleted is the only sheet in the workbook (will raise an error). Furthermore, if the user sends `*` (intentionally or by mistake) your code will delete all sheets except one. This is dangerous, so please think about your code strategy and act accordingly. An idea is to save a backup copy before deleting the sheets

```vb
Sub BackupWorkbook(wb As Workbook)
  wb.SaveCopyAs "FULL_BACKUP_PATH" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I used your suggestion and added a backup and line to check if there is more than 1 sheets in workbook

Answer (score 0):

The problem with like is it is expecting one char when using `*Name*`.

You can use InStr to find your string:

```
   If InStr(1, xWs.Name, shName ) > 0 Then
       xWs.Delete
       cnt = cnt + 1
   End If
```

Comment: I replaced this part of code:

`If xWs.Name Like xName Then
           xWs.Delete
           cnt = cnt + 1
       End If` 

and it is still not working. Same result - deleted 0 sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `InStr` instead of '`like`' and loop from last sheet to first sheet

```
   For i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set xWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i)
        If InStr(xWs.Name, shName ) > 0 Then
           xWs.Delete  
           cnt = cnt + 1    
       End If
    Next i
```

Comment: I tried and still get the same result, 0 sheets deleted. Is it possible that it doesn't run because of excel version or settings? Looks like it is not reading "*" properly. I am on Microsoft 365, Excel version 2208

Comment: delete row: xName = "*" & shName & "*" and  can check value of 'shName'  is correct?

Comment: Still not working. Even when I copy whole sheet name, macro still doesn't delete it, shows 0 deleted sheets result

Comment: You can put break point and check.

Comment: I did, I even added a line to display shName in cell = it is the same as sheet name. No extra spaces or anything.

Comment: Ok I tested it even more. When I insert first letters of sheet name, it runs macro without problems and displays result - 0 sheets deleted. But when I insert middle string from sheet name it shows run-time error 1004 method 'Delete" of object'_Worksheet' failed. It highlights xWs.Delete line

Comment: I think, your excel file has protect. try add  xWs.Unprotect before delete. refer https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/run-time-error-1004error-in-the-method-delete-for/f9cde063-9324-4939-864a-dac2762e1462